# how to retrieve total characters in a document used by the TSF manager in windows8?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, text-services-framework

i am working on Text service framework in windows8 application. in this application document manager interface using method is (*ppRange)-GetText(ec,TF_TF_IGNOREEND,wStr,WCHAR_MAX, &fetched);this method return only compossing mode text only .
how to retrieve  total characters in a document(notepad)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad isn't TSF-aware, so you can't get the entire document.  As it happens, however, edit controls (which Notepad uses) are supported by the [transitory extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tsfaware/archive/2007/05/21/transitory-extensions.aspx) service, and you can use that instead.  Just be sure to follow the rules.